# Dynamically allocating memory for three dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I don't get it. I am looking since hours on following function and don't get why I get a memory fault when walking through the array in the end. If I don't walk through it, it runs without error. The function should split the input string first by "|" and then by " ", putting all stuff in a 3 dimensional array. e.g. a string like "ls -l | grep test" should be splitted in every command in first dimension, every argument in second dimension. Third for strings.

I think the error is in dynamically allocating memory. But I don't get it.

```
char ***splitInput(char *input){

    // Here is splitted data stored (explanation in main)
    char ***commands;

    char *argT=NULL;
    char *commT=NULL;
    char *commTcopy=NULL;
    char *save_commTcopy;
    char *save_input;


    // First filter by | and new line to get commands
    commT = strtok_r(input,"|\n",&save_input);
    int c = 0;
    while(commT != NULL){

        // alloc memory for commands
        //  -> number of commands (c1+1)
        //  -> +1 for NULL command in the end
        commands = realloc(commands,sizeof(*commands)*(c+1+1));
        commTcopy = realloc(commTcopy,sizeof(*commTcopy)*strlen(commT)+1);

        // Make Copy of command
        strcpy(commTcopy,commT);
        printf("Cutting command %s\n",commT);

        // Then filter by space and new line to get arguments of command
        argT=strtok_r(commTcopy," \n",&save_commTcopy);

        char **command;
        // command pointer for easier handling
        command = *(commands+c);
        int c1 = 0;
        while(argT != NULL){
            // alloc memory for arguments
            //  -> number of commands (c1+1)
            //  -> +1 for NULL argument in the end
            command = realloc(command,sizeof(*command)*(c1+1+1));
            // alloc memory for argument string
            *(command+c1) = realloc(*(command+c1),sizeof(**command)*strlen(argT)+1);
            // Copy argument to commands three dimensional array
            strcpy(*(command+c1),argT);
            printf("-- %s\n",argT);
            // next argument
            argT = strtok_r (NULL, " \n",&save_commTcopy);
            c1++;
        }
        *(command+c1)=NULL;
        *(commands+c)=command;

        // get next command
        commT = strtok_r (NULL, "|\n",&save_input);
        c++;
    }
    *(commands+c)=NULL;

    // Walk through array for proof
    /*int c2=0;
    while(*(commands+c2)!=NULL){
        printf("Proof Command %d\n",c2);fflush(stdin);
        char **command;
        command = *(commands+c2);
        int c1=0;
        while(*(command+c1)!=NULL){
            printf("--- %s\n",*(command+c1));fflush(stdin);
            c1++;
        }
        c2++;
    }*/

    return commands;
}
```

Comment: as you are using c++ I'd recommend you to use a vector or any other stl. you do probably have an error allocating the memory.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read thorough your code. But there is at least one issue I've found.

You're using `realloc` to allocate and resize memory. The `realloc` function is generally used to resize memory. But if you pass a null pointer to it, it will directly allocate memory instead.

The issue in your code is here:

```
    //  -> +1 for NULL command in the end
    commands = realloc(commands,sizeof(*commands)*(c+1+1));
    commTcopy = realloc(commTcopy,sizeof(*commTcopy)*strlen(commT)+1);

    //...

    char **command;
    // command pointer for easier handling
    command = *(commands+c);
    int c1 = 0;
    while(argT != NULL){
        // alloc memory for arguments
        //  -> number of commands (c1+1)
        //  -> +1 for NULL argument in the end
        command = realloc(command,sizeof(*command)*(c1+1+1));
```

At each round of iteration you reallocated `commands` to a larger array, this is fine. But the issue is the allocated memory cell `*(commands + c)` contains uninitialized data, which may not be NULL. You saved that value to `command` and passed it to `realloc`. `realloc` just finds the pointer provided is not NULL so it assumes you are reallocating memory, which is in fact not. Thus a crash.

As I've understanded your code, you assigned `command` to `*(commands + c)` later so the previous `command = *(commands + c)` is just redundant, change it to `command = NULL` may fix your problem.

Comment: +1 You're on to something, but I'm not sure you knew it. The original `commands` at the top-level of the OP's allocation scheme is NOT initialized to NULLeither, so the initial `realloc()` uses an indeterminate pointer, and invokes UB. You found it happens as well for each allocation done inside that. I sense a thematic problem =P

Comment: @WhozCraig: The top level `commands` variable has automatic storage (stack) thus is automatically initialized to its default value (NULL).

Comment: Whoever told you that doesn't know their arse from a hole in the ground. If it had *static linkage* it would be zero-initialized. With automatic storage a *scalar* (which is what a **raw** pointer is) has **no** zero-initialization, and is **indeterminate**. The OP seems to understand this (see the additional initializers for the other pointers immediately below `commands`). They missed this one.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You're right. After some investigating I found that default initialization of non-class-typed variables gets indeterminate values. Maybe it's luck that prevented crash in the first place. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Thank you @XiangyanSun and @WhozCraig this was exacty the problem! I replaced `char ***commands;` by `char ***commands = NULL;` and `char **command;` by `char **command = NULL;` + erased the unneeded assignment. Now it works.